# Can anyone help me with this problem (how far a number is from another in either direction?)

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is Probably very easy for most of you...
I need a formula which will tell me how far a number is from another in either direction? Higher or lower.
Eg. The answer would be 1 if the numbers were 10 and 11 or 10 and 9.
The answer would be 3 if the numbers were 10 and 13 or 10 and 7. etc

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute value $$D(a, b) = |a - b|$$